# MYSQL parallel query performance issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlperformance

Im working on a project for my company which sells **huge amounts** of weather data to customers through a Web API. As part of that API, there is a backend service which needs to fetch data from **MYSQL database** (ver 5.1.1, InnoDB). The data set can reach amount of **50 000 rows and 12 columns** if interval is set to whole year, which is very common. MYSQL database runs on Red Hat Linux 64bit, 4 core server computer.

Query which calculates, for example, daily averages on set of **50000 rows executes in 3.5 sec**. However, if i run **4 of those queries in parallel**, execution time for each of them reaches average **8sec per query**. Im also monitoring client connection on DB and I can clearly see there are 4 threads executing each query. CPU usage on server during execution goes from **0 to cca 50% usage**.

My question is, why execution time rises if I run same query in parallel? Im I missing something or this is expected behaviour?

More server info:
  CPU: Intel Core I5-4440 @ 3.1 GHz (4 cores), 
  Memory: 8 GB

**EDIT:** Problem solved here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153388/mysql-parallel-query-performance-issue

Comment: The queries are competing for resources.  If all are slowing down, then I might speculate that the available memory is not large enough, but that is just speculation.  You need an experienced MySQL DBA to assess the situation.

Comment: You could try an update. Since MySQL 5.1 many things have been improved. Another idea would be to set a memcached backend behind the InnoDB engine, but I think it would require an update, too.

Comment: @GordonLinoff they are all slowing down, but not equaly. If i make a short delay (1sec) between two queries, first one will execute little bit faster.

Comment: If you are using MySQL 5.1 and you have real customers and you have lots of data, now is the time to find a MySQL DBA to assess your situation and make suggestions.  No doubt, upgrading the database will be one of the recommendations.

Comment: Do you have an index on the day column?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz ofc I have indexes. Query is running pretty much as expected. 3.5 sec for 50000x12 set of data is ok. At least I think so. The problem is when more of them run in parallel, which has nothing to do with indexes....if im not wrong.

Comment: Just to be sure. Can you verify that the index is being used for the GROUP BY operation and that there is no sort involved?

Comment: I think you are missing one RESOURCE... Let's assume that you have enough memory for all 4 queries to run concurrently, 4 cores sharing the processing (imagine one core per query), there is still one **SINGLE** resource that is used by all 4 queries at the same time: your hard disk. The fact that CPU reaches 50% means that the other 50% is waiting for other resources to complete, and I would bet it is the disk.

Comment: By the way, other DBMSs (I know Oracle for instance) has very clever caching mechanisms. From my experience, MySQL still needs to undergo some evolution in this area.

Comment: @FDavidov thank you for your answer, it seems disk could be the problem. I also got similar but short answer from one of DB expertees. If someone of you know how to override that problem, I'd like to know. Anyway, I'll google that.

Comment: First, you cannot **override** a problem, only **solve it**, **bypass it**, or **reduce its significance**. Second, I would suggest you attempt running 1, 2, 3 and 4 concurrent queries while monitoring all the main resources (CPU, Memory and I/O). I dear to guess that you will find interesting values when compared (e.g. Disk activities will be similar in all 4 cases since, apparently, the **Disk** is the actual bottleneck). If you do, post the statistics.

Comment: Problem solved! More details on this link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153388/mysql-parallel-query-performance-issue